# Why does this 16-bit DOS example from a book crash when I call it from C (compiled with visual studio?)

Tags: c, assembly, visual-studio-2015, x86

my OS is window 7 64-bit.

here is my code

first.c :

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern long second(int, int);

void main()
{
    int val1, val2;
    long result;

    scanf("%d %d", &val1, &val2);

    result = second(val1, val2);
    printf("%ld", result);
}
```

second.asm :

```
.model small
.code
public _second
_second proc near
    push bp
    mov bp,sp
    mov ax,[bp+4]
    mov bx,[bp+6]
    add ax,bx
    pop bp
    ret
_second endp
end
```

compiled OK, but "**mov ax,[bp+4]**" this line has error "0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000004."

what's wrong?

Comment: Why is that code 16 bit

Comment: What's the problem with copy & paste, then adopt the syntax to assembly language?

Comment: `ex_seq` or `second`?

Comment: the method by which arguments are passed depends on compiler options and the particular processor being used.  An easier way to start out is by writing the function in C and compiling it to assembly, then you can take that assembly and optimize it in whatever way you want.  That way you know that the arguments are passed correctly as expected.

Comment: You can't use 16 bit code in a 64 bit program. If you want to use assembly in a 64 bit program, you need to write 64 bit assembly.

Comment: How exactly did you build an executable out of these two source files?  Did you build a 64-bit binary?  I just noticed that you only say you're on a 64-bit OS, not that you built a 64-bit executable.

Comment: @PeterCordes Visual Studio's 64-bit assembler wouldn't accept that assembly file and I don't think its linker supports linking a 32-bit object to a 64-bit one.

Comment: @RossRidge: Oh right, I did notice earlier that `[bp+4]` would only be valid in 16 or 32-bit mode.  I wasn't ruling out the possibility that somehow the 16-bit code was assembled as 16-bit, so it wouldn't have operand-size prefixes on everything.  Ah, and I see your answer finally explains why it was trying to access memory at `0x00000004`.  That seems much more likely than that ESP happened to be 64kiB-aligned so SP=0.

Comment: student165, there are 3 answers to your question, if any of the answers is useful you may click the checkmark ✔ of the answer to accept it (this is how you reward people for their effort).

Comment: ooops! I've just begun studying to assembly. and my reference book is ms process 8086.... ;( I didn't think about before...

Comment: And I am sorry for my late check!

Comment: if you write code for 8086 then you must run it in an 8086 emulator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're assembling code in 16-bit mode and linking it into a 32-bit program which is executed in 32-bit mode.  The machine code that makes up your `second` function ends up getting interpreted differently than you expected.  This this code that is actually executed:

```
_second:
  00407800: 55                 push        ebp
  00407801: 8B EC              mov         ebp,esp
  00407803: 8B 46 04           mov         eax,dword ptr [esi+4]
  00407806: 8B 5E 06           mov         ebx,dword ptr [esi+6]
  00407809: 03 C3              add         eax,ebx
  0040780B: 5D                 pop         ebp
  0040780C: C3                 ret
```

Instead of using 16-bit registers the code uses 32-bit registers.  Instead using the BP register as a base when addressing the arguments on the stack, it uses ESI as a base.  Since ESI is not initialized to anything in the function, it holds whatever random value it happened to have before the call (eg. 0). Wherever that is isn't valid readable address so accessing it causes a crash.

Your problem is that you've taken assembly code meant to be used with a 16-bit compiler for a 16-bit operating operating system (eg. MS-DOS) and using it with a 32-bit compiler for Windows. You can't blindly cut & paste code examples like that. Here's 32-bit version of your assembly code:

```
    .MODEL FLAT
    .CODE

    PUBLIC _second
_second PROC
    push ebp
    mov  ebp, esp
    mov  eax, [ebp+8]
    mov  edx, [ebp+12]
    add  eax, edx
    pop  ebp
    ret
_second ENDP

    END
```

The `.MODEL FLAT` directive tells the assembler you're generating 32-bit code.  I've changed the code to use 32-bit registers, and adjusted the frame pointer (EBP) relative offsets to reflect the fact that stack slots in 32-bit mode are 4 bytes long. I also changed the code to use EDX instead of EBX because in 32-bit C calling convention the EBX register needs to preserved by the function, while EDX (like BX in the 16-bit C calling convention) doesn't.

Comment: re: last edit: shouldn't you be saving/restoring `ebx`?  I thought it was call-preserved in all the usual 32-bit calling conventions.  (Or using `edx` instead?  Or add from a memory source directly into eax.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Good point, I missed that. In the 16-bit calling convention BX wasn't callee-preserved.

Answer (score 0):

SP and BP are probably 0 in this specific case. Note however that SP and BP are the lowest 16-bit quarters of RSP and RBP respectively, so the stack pointer isn't really 0.

Comment: `push bp` isn't even a valid instruction in long mode, no idea, what kind of fishy thing OP is doing.

Comment: @FUZxxl actually it is valid, no idea why they did it that way (it's useless, isn't it?), but the operand size prefix turns a 64bit push into a 16bit push. E: but OP assembled that for 16bit or 32bit mode anyway otherwise those movs are unencodable

Comment: @harold That's ... interesting

Comment: Yup, it's the 16-bit addressing modes that are the show-stopper in long-mode.  @FUZxxl: 32-bit PUSH / POP is the operand-size that's unavailable in 64-bit mode.  (With `REX.W=0`, it raises #UD.)  I did once find an evil code-golf use for PUSH r64 / PUSH r16 / POP r64 to merge two 16-bit values into a 32-bit whole, in this [adler32 in 32 bytes of x86-64 machine code](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/78896/compute-the-adler-32-checksum/78972#78972)

Comment: Anyway, how would it help to have RSP and RBP aligned to 64k boundaries (i.e. SP=0)?  What you would actually need (if 16-bit addressing modes were encodeable) was for RSP = SP.  i.e. for the stack to be in the low 16 bits of virtual address space.  The can't of course be zero, or else `push bp` would fault (or something) when SP wrapped.  Oh, the caller would also have to know to pass args on the stack, as 16-bit objects.

Comment: @harold: operand-size prefix + PUSH/POP means 16-bit PUSH/POP in both 32 and 64-bit mode.  So that part of the decoding process doesn't need to change for compat vs. long mode.  It's totally normal that the operand-size prefix sets the operand-size to 16 bits in long mode, just like for instructions like ADD.  PUSH r/m16 is nearly useless, but it's probably one of those things where treating it differently would be more work for no reason.  (See my earlier comment for a code-golf use, though!)

Comment: Are you saying that SP=0 explains the OP's error message? (seems to be true).  Or are you saying that SP=0 would enable this code to work??  (Totally not true).

Comment: @PeterCordes Definitely the former. I apologise the wording was unclear.

Comment: ok, that's better, but it's still not an answer.  (I don't think this is answerable as-is, because we have no idea how the OP is building a binary.  Maybe that 16-bit code is assembled as if it were 16-bit, so no operand-size prefixes.  Or maybe it's assembled as if it were 32-bit, so everything has an operand-size prefix and no chance of working when called from a 32 or 64-bit process with a normal value of RSP.)

Answer (score 0):

Another solution to pass parameters from **.c** to **.asm** is to use the "fastcall" convention, which let you pass two parameters in registers `CX` and `DX` (actually it's `ECX` and `EDX`, but you are using 16 bit registers in your code). Next is a short example tested in VS 2013, it sends two ints (2, 5) to the asm function and the function returns the addition of those values (7) :

**first.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"

extern "C" int __fastcall second(int,int); // ◄■■ KEYWORDS "C" AND __FASTCALL.

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{   
    short int result = second(2,5); // ◄■■ "RESULT" = 7.
    return 0;
}
```

**second.asm**

```
.model small
.code
public @second@8 ◄■■ NOTICE THE @ AND THE 8.
@second@8 proc near ◄■■ NOTICE THE @ AND THE 8.
    mov ax,cx ◄■■ AX = 2.
    add ax,dx ◄■■ AX + 5 (RETURN VALUE).
    ret
@second@8 endp ◄■■ NOTICE THE @ AND THE 8.
end
```

Comment: The `.model small` directive causes the assembler to assemble the code as 16-bit code. Which means the code ends up executing as `mov eax, ecx` `add eax, edx`. Which is kinda fortunate because this matches your declaration of `second` which has a 32-bit return value and 32-bit arguments.

Comment: @RossRidge,  I was trying to keep the example as simple as possible. Anyway, I love your answer (+1), mine is an alternative.

Comment: how kind you are! but my 'reputation score' is under 15,  I can't check thumbs up.. srry

Comment: It's ok, @student165, we can wait until you got more reputation ^_º